# PWM 12V circuit with 300Hz frequency

Tags: pwm

I am trying to use microcontroller dsPIC33EPXXXGM3XX/6XX/7XX to generate a PWM 12V circuit with 300Hz frequency. I have a question about how to make sure the output is 300Hz? How to design the circuit?

Comment: use an oscilloscope or a logic analyzer to measure the the output period

Comment: the circuit design really depends on what you are driving and how much current you are switching

Answer (score 1):

To generate the signal you need to code it properly. Edit your question if you have specific questions about that but provide a link and page number reference for the section of the datasheet you don't understand.

To measure the signal you have several options:

- Oscilloscope.
- Frequency meter. Many multimeters have them.
- Attenuate to 1 V or so and feed it into the line input of your PC, record it and analyse it with a waveform viewer. Audacity might be good enough.
- Attenuate it and play it through some loudspeakers or earphones and check it against a piano. It should be between D and D# below middle C.
- Using the above approach check the frequency using a frequency meter, guitar or piano tuner app.